# Data Module in Dll with delphi?

Tags: database, delphi, dll, datamodule

I created a database program which has a problem.
I used Borland Delphi 7.x

**My Question is**

"***How to create a data module in Dll (Dynamic Link Library) With Delphi?***

Comment: A description of the observed behavior might help generate more answers.  The question as stated is too vague.

Comment: Hi Tobassum, can you clarify?
1) is it to create a tdatamodule instantiate it, and reference it with procedures exposed to the dll consumer?
2) is it that you want to dynamically create a tdatamodule and return it's handle to the consumer of a function of the dll?
3) Or are you just wondering how to add a data module to your dll project?

Answer (score 2):

You can create the code from the data module, just like you would in a normal application.
File|New|Data Module

But I am guessing that you want to create an instance of a data module in a DLL.

DataModules are no different other classes and components, and can be created in code.

```
var
  DM : TMyDataModule;
begin
  DM := TMyDataModule.Create(nil); 
  try
 // Then...   DM.MyDataSet.First; etc...
  finally
    DM.Free; 
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Open your DLL project in the IDE.  Under the File|New menu, do you see an option for Data Module?